# Can a triangular matrix have multiple determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've read that a matrix can only have one determinant, but it seems like a triangular (or diagonal) matrix would be an exception to this, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

For example, if we have a triangular matrix with det 120:

```
2   -1  0   0
0   3   -2  0
0   0   4   -3
0   0   0   5
```

What is stopping me from doing row operations to change the values on the main diagonal? If I were to divide row 2 by 3, then the det would become 40, and so on.

Am I correct in thinking this, or is there something that I've missed?

Comment: The determinant is a reduction of the matrix to a single number.  The process is well-defined and has exactly one result.  Changing the matrix to produce a different matrix will allow you to get a different determinant for a different matrix.

Comment: The determinant possess the property of $n$-linearity, and in your case its $4$-linearity. In other words, if you proceed with your row operation, then you obtain $3 \times 40 = 120;$ see the third property on page $227$ in $4.2$ of Strang's book: http://math0.bnu.edu.cn/~lijiequan/publications/Strang_Linear.Algebra.and.Its.Applications.4ed.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some row and column operations that leave the determinant unchanged. Dividing a row by a number is not one of them, as your example proves.

Comment: I suppose I should add more clarity to this question. If I were to start with a non-triangular matrix, and row reduce to get a triangular matrix, would there not be multiple outcomes depending on how I choose to get there?

Comment: Applying row operations to a matrix gives you equivalent matrices. That's useful because equivalent matrices represent equivalent systems of equations, that is, system of equations whose solutions are exactly the same. But equivalent matrices don't necessarily have the same determinant.

Comment: In other words, if you're looking to solve system of equations, you can consider its associated matrix and apply row operations **because the new matrices represent systems with the same solutions**

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: If you are looking to calculate the determinant of a matrix, you may apply **some** operations that gives you other matrices **with the same determinant**. But not all row operations do that

Comment: Row operations, however, **are useful** to calculate the determinant, because we know exactly **how the determinant changes** when each row operation is applied

Comment: In the example you used, we know that applying the row operation "divide row two by 3" will give you a matrix with one third the determinant of the original matrix